# Unable to install CentOS 7 in my computer

Tags: centos, centos-7

My computer specifications:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 8700K 3.70GHz
- RAM: 16GB
- HD: 500GB SSD, 1T HD
- Mark: Dell XPS Desktop
- GPU: Nvida GTX 1080 8G

I have created a bootable USB drive (by 3 different tools: balenaEtcher, rufus-3.8, win32diskimager).

But when I installing the system, then it stacks on the following screen:

[image]

I have tested on another computer with different specification, it was OK.

I don't know what is the problem with this computer, and this computer has a Higher configuration.

Comment: For once... that's not a very helpful error message. Are the other computers older?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, the other computer is older than this one, i5 7400 CPU. But I just stack on this screen, there is no more error message. It is why I screenshot it.

Comment: Check [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/765099/recovery-from-i8042-no-controller-found-during-boot) out, @Bahramdun Adil.

Comment: You didn't mentioned in the specs but many (or most or all??) Dell XPS do come with a discrete Nvidia graphics card. The interrupted boot that your screenshot shows can happen with many distros because they lack the proprietary drivers at the time of the installation. In this cases we need to boot the installer with additional boot parameters, typically `nomodeset` in Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives. Then use the same in the first boot and install the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I have updated the question, Yes it has Nvidia Graphic card, You mean that it is the reason of the Graphic card driver?

Comment: Yes, that's the source of the problem. I suggest googling about how to install CentOS (or similar) with newer Nvidia cards. Somewhere someone should have posted the required parameter to boot the installer and the installed system before actually installing the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I have search a lot but there was not any post about installing CentOS **with** Nvidia driver, but all was about how to install Nvidia driver **in** CentOS. But I am wondering why CentOS requires these drivers before the system being installed, there is an integrated graphics card in my computer, it can use that first if is needed during installation when installation finished then I will install the Nvidia Driver something like windows does.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Do you have any link to send me how to operate the installation scenario? Thanks!!

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Hi, I have solved the problem by redownloading the ISO file. But now a new problem happened, which when installing CentOS unable to detect the hard drive, so I cannot select the drive to install on, there is two hard drive in the computer, SSD 500, and 1T Hd.

Comment: use AHCI instead of RAID or Intel RST.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yes, that works. Thank you very much!!